# ¿Porqué me salta el error "Cannot add foreign key constraint" al crear la tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql, sintaxis

Muy buenas. Estoy intentando hacer un campo referenciando a mi primera tabla, pero me salta este error y no logro comprender porqué. Esto es lo que he intentado.

```
mysql> create database prueba1;                                                                                                                                                                 
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)                                                                                                                                                             

mysql> use prueba1;                                                                                                                                                                             
Database changed                                                                                                                                                                                
mysql> create table ja (
    -> nombre varchar(255),
    -> equipoA varchar(255),
    -> primary key(nombre));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)                                                                                                                                                            

mysql> create table je (
    -> jejo varchar(255),
    -> e varchar(255),
    -> primary key (jejo),
    -> foreign key (e) references ja ( equipoA));
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es convertir en clave única o índice el campo `equipoA`. En caso contrario no te permitirá crear la relación:

```
create table ja (
 nombre varchar(255),
 equipoA varchar(255),
 primary key(nombre),
 unique(equipoA));

create table je (
 jejo varchar(255),
 e varchar(255),
 primary key (jejo),
 foreign key (e) references ja (equipoA));
```

Puedes ver que funciona en línea en [este enlace](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bQtvsGHvmE6VJMd2G3qDkB/0).

En el ejemplo he usado `UNIQUE` (clave única) pero, como he explicado al principio, también valdría `KEY` (índice).

Si deseas convertir el campo en `UNIQUE` o `KEY` sin perder los datos existentes usa:

```
ALTER TABLE ja
  ADD KEY(equipoA);
```